# boost variant: Get pointer of generic class providing a variant

Tags: c++, boost

I have a `boost::variant` defined like this:

```
typedef boost::variant<Rectangle, Circle> Shape;
```

Now I want to get a `Shape` pointer from a `Rectangle`:

```
Rectangle *rectanglePointer = new Rectangle();
Shape *shapePointer = rectanglePointer;
```

But it doesn't work. What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Variants don't work that way.

They're specifically intended for static polymorphism.

You /can/ store runtime polymorphic references (or pointers) but you'll still need to use `boost::get<>` or a visitor to extract the actual value.

In your case, the `Shape` is clearly not a base class of `Rectangle`, which is why the compiler will deny the static conversion (up-cast is not available for unrelated types `Rectangle` and `Shape`).

### Variants, simple

A simple example with variant:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed8b76b41316a7da)**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Circle {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Circle) {
        return os << "Circle";
    }
};

struct Rectangle {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Rectangle) {
        return os << "Rectangle";
    }
};

using Shape = boost::variant<Circle, Rectangle>;


int main() {

    Shape shape = Rectangle();
    std::cout << shape << "\n";

    shape = Circle();
    std::cout << shape << "\n";

}
```

### Variants: `area(Shape)` implementation

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0efa82c2a1dd4ac5)**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Point { double x,y; };

struct Circle {

    Point centre;
    double radius;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Circle) {
        return os << "Circle";
    }
};

struct Rectangle {
    Point topleft, bottomright;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Rectangle) {
        return os << "Rectangle";
    }
};

struct area_f : boost::static_visitor<double> {
    double operator()(Rectangle const& r) const {
        return std::abs(r.bottomright.x - r.topleft.x) * 
               std::abs(r.bottomright.y - r.topleft.y);
    }
    double operator()(Circle const& r) const {
        return (r.radius*r.radius) * M_PI;
    }
};

using Shape = boost::variant<Circle, Rectangle>;

double area(Shape const& s) {
    return boost::apply_visitor(area_f(), s);
}

int main() {

    Shape shape = Rectangle { { 1,1 }, { 5,5 } };
    std::cout << shape << ": " << area(shape) << "\n";

    shape = Circle { { 10, 10 },  5 };
    std::cout << shape << ": " << area(shape) << "\n";

}
```

### Dynamic polymorphism

The same using the polymorphism that you can use in other languages:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/889eae472a3abf7c)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct Point { double x,y; };

struct Shape {
    virtual ~Shape() {}
    virtual double area() const = 0;
  protected:
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const = 0;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Shape const& s) {
        s.print(os);
        return os;
    }
};

struct Circle : Shape {
    Circle(Point c, double r) : centre(c), radius(r) {}

    Point centre;
    double radius;

    virtual double area() const override {
        return (radius*radius) * M_PI;
    }

    virtual ~Circle() { }

  protected:
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override {
        os << "Circle";
    }
};

struct Rectangle : Shape {
    Rectangle(Point tl, Point br) : topleft(tl), bottomright(br) {}

    Point topleft, bottomright;

    virtual double area() const override {
        return std::abs(bottomright.x - topleft.x) * 
               std::abs(bottomright.y - topleft.y);
    }

    virtual ~Rectangle() { }
  protected:
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override {
        os << "Rectangle";
    }

};

int main() {
    Rectangle r { { 1,1 }, { 5,5 } };

    {
        Shape const& shape = r;
        std::cout << shape << ": " << shape.area() << "\n";
    }

    Circle    c { { 10, 10 },  5 };
    {
        Shape const& shape = c;
        std::cout << shape << ": " << shape.area() << "\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Added three contrasting samples live on Coliru

Answer (score 0):

A Shape is a box that can contain either a Rectangle or a Circle. If you have a Rectangle and want to put it in a box, you need an actual physical box for that. You cannot just declare that this place with such and such address, where the rectangle happens to be, is now a box, because there's no box.